# How to execute multiple spring batch steps inside a single job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

```
@Qualifier("billingJob")
@Bean
public Job billingJob(@Qualifier("fetchAgreementTasklet")Step fetchAgreementTasklet,
@Qualifier("fetchAgreementRecurringItemsTasklet") Step fetchAgreementRecurringItemsTasklet,
@Qualifier("fetchItemsHistoryTasklet") Step fetchItemsHistoryTasklet ,
@Qualifier("populateAgreementStep") Step populateAgreementStep,
@Qualifier("populateRecurringItemStep") Step populateRecurringItemStep ,
@Qualifier("populateRecurringItemHistoryStep") Step populateRecurringItemHistoryStep ) {
        
  return jobsBuilderFactory.get("billingJob")                                
           .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
           .flow(fetchAgreementTasklet)
           .next(fetchAgreementRecurringItemsTasklet)
           .next(fetchItemsHistoryTasklet)
                
           .next(populateAgreementStep).next(populateRecurringItemStep)
           .next(populateRecurringItemHistoryStep)
           .end().build();
}

    @Qualifier("populateRecurringItemStep")
    @Bean
    public Step populateRecurringItemStep(
    @Qualifier("recurringItemReader") ItemReader<RecurringItemRaw> recurringItemReader,
    @Qualifier("recurringItemProcessor") ItemProcessor<RecurringItemRaw, RecurringItem> recurringItemProcessor,
    @Qualifier("recurringItemWriter") ItemWriter<RecurringItem> recurringItemWriter) {
       return stepBuilderFactory.get("populateRecurringItemStep")
        .<RecurringItemRaw, RecurringItem> chunk(10)
        .reader(recurringItemReader).processor(recurringItemProcessor)
        .writer(recurringItemWriter).build();
    } 

@Qualifier("recurringItemReader")
@Bean
public ItemReader<RecurringItemRaw> recurringItemReader() {
FlatFileItemReader<RecurringItemRaw> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<RecurringItemRaw>();
String file = salesforceConfiguration       .getFileLocation(SalesforceConfiguration.TYPE_AGREEMENT_ITEMS);
    LOG.info("::::::: Reading RecurringItem File ::::::: " + file);
    reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(file));
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<RecurringItemRaw>() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "id", "name", "agreementId",
                            "cost", "quantity" });
                }
            });
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<RecurringItemRaw>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(RecurringItemRaw.class);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return reader;
}

@Qualifier("recurringItemProcessor")
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<RecurringItemRaw, RecurringItem> recurringItemprocessor() {
return new RecurringItemProcessor();
}

@Qualifier("recurringItemWriter")
@Bean
public ItemWriter<RecurringItem> recurringItemWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
JdbcBatchItemWriter<RecurringItem> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<RecurringItem>();
writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<RecurringItem>());
writer.setSql(PostgresqlDBQuery.INSERT_RECURRING_ITEM_QRY);
writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
return writer;
}
```

recurringItemprocessor() is used to convert the string values to other formats

recurringItemWriter() is used to insert record into my postgresql database

recurringItemReader() is used to read the csv file.

---

This is the processor class

```
public class RecurringItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<RecurringItemRaw, RecurringItem> {
    
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RecurringItemProcessor.class.getName());

    @Override
    public RecurringItem process(final RecurringItemRaw recurringItemRaw) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Processing recurring item");
        final RecurringItem item = new RecurringItem(); 
        item.setId(recurringItemRaw.getId());
        item.setName(recurringItemRaw.getName());
        item.setAgreementId(recurringItemRaw.getAgreementId());
        if (recurringItemRaw.getCost().trim().isEmpty()){
            item.setCost(BigDecimal.ZERO);
        }
        else{
            item.setCost(new BigDecimal(recurringItemRaw.getCost())); 
        }
        if (recurringItemRaw.getQuantity().trim().isEmpty()){
            item.setQuantity(0);
        }else{
            item.setQuantity(new BigDecimal(recurringItemRaw.getQuantity()).intValue());
        }
        LOG.info(item.toString());
        return item;
    }

}
```

---

I'm having issue with "populateRecurringItemStep" where this step running in a endloop.
How to fix this issue ..
I'm using the spring boot no xml configurations ..

Comment: Can you add also populateRecurringItemStep configuration or component?

Comment: Still nothing that rings the bell. Guess you can post full configuration and also problematic reader, processor and writer.

Comment: Please have a look now i edit the code

Comment: Your reader may not be following the ItemReader contract. When all items have been read, the reader should return null. Debug through your ItemReader. It may be reading the same line over and over.

Comment: I'm reading item by item so it should return the processed item . If i return null instead of the object there will be no items saving in the database.  In this case it is not reading the same line over and over, it repeats all the items so i want to end once all the items are read..

Comment: Can you try to loose flow, I do not see any need for it, you have steps which are done sequentially so try to loose it and also end() on the end. Long shot but can be problem, I do not see anything else strange.

Comment: Can you see what the reader is returning?  A step is considered complete once the reader returns null.  If it never returns null...it will never end.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `flow()`, use `start()`, as following :

```
return jobsBuilderFactory.get("billingJob")                                
           .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
           .start(fetchAgreementTasklet)
           .next(fetchAgreementRecurringItemsTasklet)
           .next(fetchItemsHistoryTasklet)

           .next(populateAgreementStep).next(populateRecurringItemStep)
           .next(populateRecurringItemHistoryStep)
           .end().build();
}
```

Comment: `.end()` is not available when using `start()` and `next()`, it's only for `flow()`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to do something like this:

```
    @Bean
    public Step stepOne(){
        return steps.get("stepOne")
                .tasklet(new MyTaskOne())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepTwo(){
        return steps.get("stepTwo")
                .tasklet(new MyTaskTwo())
                .build();
    } 

    @Bean
    public Job demoJob(){
        return jobs.get("demoJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(stepOne())
                .next(stepTwo())
                .build();
    }
```